# Customizing text-wrap inside of a div

Tags: html, css

Basically what's going on is I'm wanting to add a little bit of styling to my text-wrapping, the styling that I'm looking for is to indent after the text wraps, so the text will look like this for example:

```
This is text that should be 
    wrapped.
```

However currently it looks like this:

```
This is text that should be 
wrapped.
```

Also, I'm trying to figure out how to properly disable the left-right scroll-bar in my chat-area and apply text-wrapping for ***"words"*** that don't have any spaces. Example below

**Current: (Applies horizontal scroll)**

```
oejgoewgomgepoegwmopewjopvwemxdivheiwvmewcmoewmvnvpoewcewocmewinvew
```

**Needed:**

```
oejgoewgomgepoegwmop
    ewjopvwemxdivhei
    wvmewcmoewmvnvpo
    ewcewocmewinvew
```

I've supplied images to show you guys what I currently have and what I'm looking for below

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I want:**

[image]

Looking on stack-overflow showed that setting the

```
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

property would only show the scroll bar horizontally, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

If you need the css for my div, it's below:

```
#chatBoxDiv {
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    height: 20%;
    width: 29%;
    left: 1%;
    bottom: 6%;
    opacity: 0.6;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Show your HTML markup and explain clearly what you want, e.g. should strings be brutally broken at arbitrary po ints oe what? And ask *one* question, and omit images that do not contribute to understanding the question.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is `word-break: break-all` for breaking long strings, and `text-indent: -15px;` and `padding-left` for indentation:

```css
#chatBoxDiv {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
    font-size: 12px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    word-break: break-all;
    padding-left: 15px;
    text-indent: -15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chatBoxDiv">oejgoewgomgepoegwmopewjopvwemxdivheiwvmewcmoewmvnvpoewcewocmewinvew</div>
```

Comment: Here's a tricky one, is it possible to not make it break, and instead move the word down if it is a word? for example: (Sorry for the linked image) http://gyazo.com/8e632b0f19772df3dc8917370fcc0a06 while keeping the long strings broken up?

Comment: It should behave like this and take word to the next line if it's a word http://jsfiddle.net/yng8wyua/

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
#chatBoxDiv
    margin-left:40px;
    text-indent:-40px;
}
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/1ddafgc6/)

Answer (score -1):

word-wrap: break-word;
text-overflow: ellipsis;

Comment: Please provide more information to your answer. The goal is to not only offer a solution, but for the OP to understand the solution.

Comment: Not at all what was asked for.